Charger IC cannot charge with Type-C Data+Charging Cable on USB Port
I am using Texas Instruments(TI) BQ25713 Charger IC. When I use a basic type-c charging cable, the charger accepts and start charging very well however when I use a qualified type-c charging and upgrade cable(by JBL), the charger does not accept it to charging on USB Port.
I use the qualified type-c charging cable to charging phone, vacuum cleaner, speaker and others very well but the charger doesn't accept that.
Note: If I use a 5V/2A or 5V/1A adapter, the charger IC accepts both cable. I've tried other ports and PC. The problem is only when the IC charging the battery with this cable on a USB Port.
To summarize;
If it charging with data+charging cable on adapter, it works
If it charging with data+charging cable on USB Port, it not works
If it charging with only charging cable on adapter, it works
If it charging with only charging cable on USB Port, it works

It works.

It doesn't works.
CHARGER SCHEMATIC

TYPE-C SCHEMATIC


You don't post the schematics so we can't know why it does not charge. Also that's not a Type-C cable as it has Type-A on one end. The cables should be identical but we also don't know how your cables are internally working. One of the cables may be against USB specs but we can't know which one, you need to measure which one is.

I've added the type-c schematics

No you haven't. Edit: Oh you have. Remove the "answer" with the schematics and edit it to the question. And you never provided info on the cables. "Charging only Type-C" makes no sense as all Type-C cables are required to have data or they are not usable.

The USB A plug has 4 pins. +5V, ground, D+ and D-.
A USB data (upgrade) lead will connect all 4 pins. When charging, the D+ and D- are used by the device to tell the power supply what it needs. Unfortunately, the USB specification has evolved over the years, allowing either data communication or resistors connected to D+ and D-. There have also been a few non standard proprietary solutions. The end result is that your device isn't successfully telling the computer what it wants, and the computer is refusing to allow 2A to an unknown device.
A charging only lead doesn't pass through D+ and D-, probably adding the resistors in the USB A plug. This time, the computer thinks it's OK and allows 2A to flow.

I've added the type-c schematics, There is no D+ and D- pins, seems to be caused by missing D+ and D- pins.  Am I right?

@Melisa your design does not use D+/D- pins so it does not matter what cable you use. Your design also uses wrong CC resistors but you also use Type-A to Type-C cable so the power source cannot detect that. Also the Type-A to Type-C cables must indicate to your device it supports 900mA but your device does not try to detect how much current is available and tries to draw 2A without negotiation.

@Justme 1) Then D+/D- is unneccessary with this IC. 2) Yes, you are right, I had to use 5.1K instead of 10k, I will replace these with 5.1K on next design. 3) I have seen that Type-A to Type-C cable supports up to 900mA but the IC requests and takes 2A. I asked this to TI but I did not get clear reply.

@Melisa You have no method of "requesting" 2A, the circuit simply takes what it wants without knowing if it is available. It does not even check how much the Type-C cable advertizes being available, as there are compliant and non-compliant cables. It's not the TI chip fault there is no handshake of any kind, it's the fault of the circuit that was designed to tell the chip to draw 2A without handshake.

@Justme in fact BQ25713 can programmable via I2C. I set ChargeCurrent and Current Limit but it does not affected. Then as you said the fault is circuit design.

What you say is true of a USB data cable, but I see no particular reason to trust that an oddly named "charging and upgrade" cable is any sort of standard-compliant USB data cable.  Sounds like something specialized for a wireless headset/wireless speaker, given the brand name.
